# Get URL parameters in JS that don't have values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the parameters in a URL even though they don't have a value using JavaScript.

```
http://example.com/?Germany&France&Norway&Sweden
```

This URL contains 4 parameters with the name of some countries. I want to get this list of countries in JavaScript, ideally as an array. There are many examples that retrieve the values from key-value parameters, where you have to provide the key and some Regex will return the value.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck? Can you show us some examples of what you did already.

Comment: there's probably a few gazillion examples of how to parse out query parameters in JS. just because you don't have values doesn't make the keys any more special...

Comment: `var countries = location.search.substring(1).split("&");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `split()` :

```
var my_string = "http://example.com/?Germany&France&Norway&Sweden";
var parameters = my_string.split('?')[1];
var params_array = parameters.split('&');
//["Germany","France","Norway","Sweden"]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function noValParams(url) {
  var noValue = [];
  var qp = x.split("?")[1];
  [].forEach.call(qp.split("&"), function (inst) {
    if (inst.indexOf("=") == -1 || inst.indexOf("=") == inst.length - 1) {
      noValue.push(inst);
    }
  });
  return noValue;
}
```

[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmozwx1m/1/)

Split the URL with a `?` and take the index 1. Then split the remaining part with `&` and check the position of `=`. Either it should not exist or it should be last index.

This function will return a array of params with value blank.